# How does Dask decide whether to rerun a task or not

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm very new to Dask and trying to build a system to execute a computation graph with dependencies. However I'm very confused by the fact that some tasks are being executed twice although they have a static signature. E.g.:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov 12 2019, 11:34:05)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from dask.distributed import Client
>>> client = Client()
>>> def a():
...   print("a")
...
>>> client.gather(client.submit(a))
a
>>> client.gather(client.submit(a))
a
>>> client.submit(a)
<Future: pending, key: a-a5eb50e9015acdf60b1094aa4e467e00>
a
>>> client.submit(a)
<Future: finished, type: builtins.NoneType, key: a-a5eb50e9015acdf60b1094aa4e467e00>
>>> client.gather(client.submit(a))
>>> client.gather(client.submit(a))
>>>
```

So it looks like `a()` is executed for each call using `client.gather(client.submit(a))`, but only until I call `client.submit(a)` on its own, after which the same `Future` is reused and the function is no longer called. Why is that?

In my computation graph, this will be a problem when two tasks rely on the same task, which should be executed only once. My current approach to handle such dependencies (recursively) is the following:

```
from dask.distributed import Client, worker_client

def x(n):
    dgraph = {
        'a': [],
        'b': ['a'],
        'c': ['b', 'a'],
        'd': ['b', 'c']
        }
    print(n)
    with worker_client() as client:
        client.gather(list(client.submit(x, d) for d in dgraph[n]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client()
    result = client.submit(x, 'd')
    client.gather(result)
```

Interestingly, python's output when executing that script is not stable:

```
$ python test_dask2.py
d
b
c
a
b
a
a
$ python test_dask2.py
d
b
c
a
distributed.scheduler - CRITICAL - Tried writing to closed comm: {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'x-bff0c0d6e4239ae9c5beaed070018a1e'}
distributed.scheduler - CRITICAL - Tried writing to closed comm: {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'x-59dc11a9fc2db8a0885e47d3e5891304'}
$
```

Is there a way to ensure that a given task, with given inputs, is executed only once even if I submit it several times? If I understand the [documentation](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/client.html#pure-functions-by-default) properly, that should be the normal behaviour. If the call to `print` is a side-effect that prevents that, why is it not consistent and how can I e.g. prevent a task that generates an output file from being executed twice?

Also, what's the error at the end, which doesn't always occur?

EDIT:

I think I figured out why some of my tasks were being run several times in the second snippet: the hash value that dask's `submit` is assigning to tasks for identification seems to sometimes vary even when submitting the same task several times (and even before the task completes and goes out of scope). Setting the `key` parameter to a fixed value (e.g. the task's name) in `submit` fixes that problem.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: dask keeps a result in memory while something needs it. In these cases, "need" can be either a future in your session or another task that depends on the result.

In a line like `client.gather(client.submit(a))`, the future generated by `submit` is forgotten immediately after it is gathered. In a line like `client.submit(a)`, the future generated is stored in the "last result" variable `_` of the session, and so remains remembered and the cluster does not clear it.

If you wanted more control, you can assign these variables:

```
fut = client.submit(a)  # sets func running, keeps hold of the future
fut2 = client.submit(a)  # uses already existing task to get result
client.gather(fut), fut.result() # get results
del fut2, fut  #  "forget" futures, and have cluster release them
```

Remember to use the dashboard to see the current state of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for the following documentation page https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/memory.html